# Searching string in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, find, richtextbox

This is my code on finding text in my richtextbox and highlighting it:

```
        int start = 0;
        int indexOfSearchText = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int startindex = 0;

            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
                startindex = FindMyText(textBox1.Text.Trim(), start, richTextBox1.Text.Length);

            // If string was found in the RichTextBox, highlight it
            if (startindex >= 0)
            {
                // Set the highlight color as red
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                // Find the end index. End Index = number of characters in textbox
                int endindex = textBox1.Text.Length;
                // Highlight the search string
                richTextBox1.Select(startindex, endindex);
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                // mark the start position after the position of
                // last search string
                start = startindex + endindex;
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("0 occurence in richtextbox");
            }
        }

        public int FindMyText(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
        {
            // Unselect the previously searched string
            if (searchStart > 0 && searchEnd > 0 && indexOfSearchText >= 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Undo();
            }

            // Set the return value to -1 by default.
            int retVal = -1;

            // A valid starting index should be specified.
            // if indexOfSearchText = -1, the end of search
            if (searchStart >= 0 && indexOfSearchText >= 0)
            {
                // A valid ending index
                if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
                {
                    // Find the position of search string in RichTextBox
                    indexOfSearchText = richTextBox1.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
                    if (indexOfSearchText != -1)
                    {
                        // Return the index to the specified search text.
                        retVal = indexOfSearchText;
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start = 0;
            indexOfSearchText = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when it reaches the end of the richtextBox1, it did not restart at the beginning again! I want to loop it again to the start after reaching the end of the richtextBox1.text.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    startindex = FindMyText(textBox1.Text.Trim(), start, richTextBox1.Text.Length);
    if(startindex == -1 && start > 0) // Not found string and not searching from beginning
    {
        // Wrap search
        int oldStart = start;
        start = 0;
        startindex = FindMyText(textBox1.Text.Trim(), start, oldStart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is useful for searching a text in richtextbox and highlighting the text in round direction.I was using textbox in richtextbox.i,m entering the search text in textbox and pressing enter button for find next.Initially i,m declaring two values as 0 for start and  indexOfSearchText.

int start = 0;
int indexOfSearchText = 0;

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

```
     private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)   
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)


            {                   
                 int startindex = 0;

                if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
                {


                    startindex = FindMyText(textBox1.Text.Trim(), start, richTextBox1.Text.Length);

                    if (startindex == -1 && start >= 0) // Not found string and not searching from beginning
                    {
                        // Wrap search
                       // int oldStart = start;
                        start = 0;
                        startindex = FindMyText(textBox1.Text.Trim(), start, richTextBox1.Text.Length);
                    }


                }


                // If string was found in the RichTextBox, highlight it
                if (startindex >= 0)
                {
                    // Set the highlight color as red
                    richTextBox1.Select(startindex, textBox1.TextLength);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                   // richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                    // Find the end index. End Index = number of characters in textbox
                    int endindex = textBox1.Text.Length;
                    // Highlight the search string
                    richTextBox1.Select(startindex, endindex);
                    // mark the start position after the position of
                    // last search string
                    start = startindex + endindex;
                }

            }
        }



        public int FindMyText(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
        {
            // Unselect the previously searched string
            if (searchStart > 0 && searchEnd > 0 && indexOfSearchText >= 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Undo();
            }

            // Set the return value to -1 by default.
            int retVal = -1;

            // A valid starting index should be specified.
            // if indexOfSearchText = -1, the end of search
            if (searchStart >= 0 && indexOfSearchText >= 0)
            {
                // A valid ending index
                if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
                {
                    // Find the position of search string in RichTextBox
                    indexOfSearchText = richTextBox1.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
                    if (indexOfSearchText != -1)
                    {
                        // Return the index to the specified search text.
                        retVal = indexOfSearchText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        start = 0;
                        indexOfSearchText = 0;
                        //return indexOfSearchText;
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal;

        }

 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            start = 0;
            indexOfSearchText = 0;
            string temp = richTextBox1.Text;
            richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            richTextBox1.Text = temp;
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

Comment: Please take time to properly format your answer and add explanation to it.